# Using If,Then function in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a retail store that sells items on consignment for a fee that varies based on `Selling Price`. 
So my question is how do I write a formula that checks the selling price and then charges the correct consignment fee to calculate the net based on the following schedule:

```
  When selling price is over $400 then charge = 20%
  When Selling price is $100 to $400 then charge = 30%
  When Selling price is under $100 then charge = 40%
```

Answer (score 1):

**BLUF: use nested IF statements (an IF inside an IF)** --

Example:

=IF(A2>=400, (A2*0.2), (IF(400 > A2 >= 100, (A2 *0.3),  (A2*0.4))))

Or use the below if you suspect someone will foolishly enter a negative number or something nonsensical:

=IF(A2>=400, (A2*0.2), (IF(400 > A2 >= 100, (A2 *0.3), (IF(A2 < 100, (A2*0.4), (0))))))

That may look complex, but let's break it down from the beginning.

The basic formula for the IF statement:

=IF(testCondition, (resultIfTrue), (resultIfFalse))

One IF statement will only allow you to do two of your 3 conditions:

=IF(A1 > 400, (A1 * .20), (A1 * .30))

The above basically says that if the number in cell A1 is greater than 400, then the value in your current cell (e.g. B2) is A1 * 20%. But if the number in A1 is NOT greater than 400, the value in your cell will be A1 * 30%.

But how do we calculate the range you were asking (i.e. 100 - 400) and how do we add in a third possibility (i.e. the possibility that the number is less than 100)?

The answer is to use a nested IF.  You can tell the cell what it's value should be if the condition is true, but you can test another condition if the answer is false (i.e. the *next* IF statement stands in the place of resultIfFalse.

=IF(testCondition, (resultIfTrue), (IF(testCondition, (resultIfTrue), (resultIfFalse))))

The above can handle 3 different scenarios.  Out of the IFs above, you could also replace the second IFs *resultIfFalse* with yet another IF statement, and so on.  You can nest up to 64 IF statements.

Extra Resources:
http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/using-multiple-if-statements-excel

http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/tipsandfaqs/qt/nested_if.htm

Answer (score 1):

Nested **IF** functions are not user friendly and require hardcoding your variables (percentages). My suggestion would always be to have a small table of values elsewhere: eg. put the following in **A1:B3**

`0  0.4
100 0.3
401 0.2`

Assuming your data is in **D1** you can use the following formula in **E1** and drag down if necessary

`=INDEX($B$1:$B$3,MATCH($D1,$A$1:$A$3,1))`

This way you can change your boundaries/ add more conditions easily without more nested **IF** statements

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

`=IF(B1<100,B1*40%,IF((B1>=100)*AND(B1<=400),B1*30%,IF(B1>100,B1*20%,"Invalid Price"))`
This formula contains nested-ifs and a logical AND condition which will give the result.